# Can i move the world wonder when its complete?

Tags: paradise-island

When creating the foundation's of my world wonder I put it in a place where its now covering other places.

Is it possible to relocate it when its complete, or am I better off restarting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your out of luck on both fronts. You can't move or even cancel it once placed.

More information here:

http://paradiseislandhd.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_of_the_World

Comment: Cheers for the link, thats a shame. I'm on level 25 and its right in the middle of my map hiding loads of the island.

Answer (score 1):

You can move it with a world wonder [scroll](http://paradiseislandhd.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolls).

> Relocate World Wonder building. Available via a limited chest offer or from completing the Birthday Cake event